# Specific responsive grid template configuration

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

Is there a chance I can create the following grid:

1. after every 2 rows of 4 grid items, there is 1 row with 2 grid items
2. after every 2 rows of 3 grid items, there is 1 row with 2 grid items

Here is my solution that unfortunately doesn't work for the first row:

```css
.root {
    display: grid;

    @include screenLarge {
        grid-gap: 50px 12px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 4fr 4fr);
    }

    @include screenMedium {
        grid-gap: 30px 10px;
    }
}

.item {
    @include screenLarge {
        position: relative;
        grid-column: auto / span 2;

        /* Featured */
        &:nth-of-type(15n + 4) {
            grid-area: 4 / col4-start / last-line / 1;
        }

        /* Larger regular on left */
        &:nth-of-type(27n + 11),
        &:nth-of-type(27n + 26) {
            grid-column: 1 / span 4;
        }

        /* Larger regular on right */
        &:nth-of-type(27n),
        &:nth-of-type(27n + 12) {
            grid-column: 5 / span 4;
        }
    }

    @include screenMedium {
        /* Featured */
        &:nth-of-type(7n + 3) {
            grid-column: auto / span 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to display x items or y items depending of the screen width :

```css
.container{
  width:100px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.item{
    text-align:center;
}
@media (min-width: 993px){
  .item{
    width:25%; 
  }
  .item:nth-of-type(10n+9),.item:nth-of-type(10n+10){
    width: 50%; 
    background-color:yellow;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 992px){
  .item{
    width:33.33%; 
  }
  .item:nth-of-type(8n+7),.item:nth-of-type(8n+8){
    width: 50%; 
    background-color:bisque;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
</div>
```

You can click on full page after running the code snipper to check the result on bigger screen width